# Spring boot application - failed to start

Tags: spring-boot

I have recently upgraded spring boot from 1.x to 2.2.1. I am able to deploy most of the modules. For one of the modules I am getting below error while deploying in openshift.

```
***************************_APPLICATION FAILED TO START_***************************__Description:__Failed to bind properties under 'spring.jackson.serialization' to java.util.Map<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature, java.lang.Boolean>:__    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature, java.lang.Boolean>]__Action:__Update your application's configuration_
```

I have added `jackson-databind` and `jackson-core` dependencies but no luck.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.1</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In local environment the deployment works fine.

**application.yml:**

````
  application:
    name: @project.name@
server:
  port: 8085
  context: /*
  sessionAPIUrl: localhost:8087
  sessionAPIUri: /AppMS/user/session
  account:
    host: http://localhost:8080
    remote:
      dev: http://localhost:8080
      test: http://10.8.99.8:8080
      staging: https://stg2-tic.myapp.com
      prod: https://ss1.myapp.com
    uri:
      data: AppMS/service/test
      
javax.persistence.query.timeout: 120000

#mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database: 
spring.data.mongodb.host: 
spring.data.mongodb.port: 22017
spring.data.mongodb.database: ticnf
spring.data.mongodb.username: ******
spring.data.mongodb.password: ******


#JMX setting
endpoints.jmx.unique-names: true

#logging setup
logging.level.org.springframework.web: WARN
logging.level.com.myapp: INFO

# Logging pattern for the console
logging.pattern.console: "%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS zzz}, TYPE= %-5p, SESSIONID=%X{sessionID}, CLIENT_IP=%X{UserIPAddress}, REQID=%X{requestID}, SSOUID=%X{ssoUserId}, ticUID=%X{ticUserID},  APP=%X{APP}, REQUESTURI=%X{requestURI}, CLASS=%c{1}, METHOD=%M, MSG=%m%n"

# Logging pattern for file
logging.pattern.file: "%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS zzz}, TYPE= %-5p, SESSIONID=%X{sessionID}, CLIENT_IP=%X{UserIPAddress}, REQID=%X{requestID}, SSOUID=%X{ssoUserId}, ticUID=%X{ticUserID},  APP=%X{APP}, REQUESTURI=%X{requestURI}, CLASS=%c{1}, METHOD=%M, MSG=%m%n"

logging.file: logs/ticms/ticms.log

#kafka configuration
kafka:
  broker:
    address: localhost:9099
  zookeeper:
    connect: localhost:2191
  consumerId: tic.account

tic.secret: where to store this is an question? DB/File?

spring:
  profiles: dev
  jackson:
    serialization:
      INDENT_OUTPUT: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    url: jdbc:db2://192.0.0.1:9000/sdb1:currentSchema=DEV1;
    username: *****
    password: *****
    platform: db2
    schema: classpath:schema-db2-stg.sql
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
        default_schema: DEV1
server:
  domainURI: https://stg-us-api.myapp.com/oauth2/v1

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type: trace
org.hibernate.type: trace
org.springframework.transaction: debug```
````

Comment: Can you add your application.properties or application.yml file? Thanks.

Comment: Upgrades from Spring Boot 1.x to 2.x has plenty of breaking changes have you checked the migration documentation?

Comment: @JoãoDias added

Comment: #1 If you achieve to create a minimal mvp with the issue, it would be easy to help you #2 I think `spring.data.mongodb.host` is not a valid yml property

Comment: @JRichardsz we have used it in other projects. I have intesionally removed the host ip for security reasons.

Comment: Have you tried removing the version from `jackson-databind` and `jackson-annotations`? They should be already included in Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, initially jackson-databind was not present in pom. I added them later once I received the error.

Comment: But have you removed the version configuration? It might happen that you have incompatible versions.

Comment: no it's not a compatible issue. I have validated that. Removed the versions as well.

Comment: #1 I think the problem is one key in your yml. #2 If you achieve to create a minimal mvp with the issue, it would be easy to help you. #3 Also set `debug:true` and compile it using shell. Share us the log

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone.
When I saw the error message saying "_*Update your application's configuration*" , I was sure something is wrong in my application.yml. But in local it was deploying fine.

In paas it was failing, hence I tried to check all the paas related config files. paas-pom was ok. FInally I found application-paassit.yml file was missing. This file was mentioned in my config map for that application in openshift.
I added the file and it was solved.